Perception of shared authorship in pure mathematics
Suppose that a paper published on a very good journal has two authors, A and B, and that A is the supervisor of the PhD student B. The paper concerns a research that is not strictly related to the PhD thesis of the student.
What is the "default assumption" of a mathematician about the contribution of the two authors? From what I see, there are two extreme cases:

According to a certain view, many experienced mathematicians will tend to believe that all the main ideas were produced by A, while B basically did the homework that A told them to do.
According to others, many will believe that B made most of the effort while A just gave some suggestions and signed the work.

Which one is closer to the average "default assumption"? If that matters, I'm thinking to a paper in pure math, say algebraic geometry, set theory, number theory...

Unless things have changed, supervisors in pure math aren't normally co-authors of the student's work, especially that of the dissertation research.

Also, in pure math papers, authors are usually listed alphabetically by last name. So the default assumption is A was listed first because their last name is alphabetically before B's last name.

While the question is certainly answerable, I have a hard time seeing what benefit getting an answer will have. Whatever the answer is should not change who the authors end up being on a given paper (since that is based on who contributed sufficiently to be an author).

I just wanted to know how an already existing paper will be percieved.

I hope this isn't too dated as I've been out of the game for a while. People will correct me if I'm wrong, I'm sure. But...
In my experience in pure math, which I carried over to CS, supervisors aren't co-authors of a student's dissertation work, but are acknowledged in resulting papers. This is true even when the advisor supplies the problem to the student and offers guidance along the way. I've found it true, also, when the supervisor could have done the research and come up with satisfying conclusions, but left it to the student.
Second, unlike other fields, pure math usually lists authors alphabetically, so one can't conclude from author "order" anything about contributions. A paper might have a contributions paragraph to make that clear, however.
I would, myself, conclude that such a paper, listing supervisor and student as authors was from a separate collaboration, treating the two (more?) as colleagues.
One issue with pure math is that a five minute conversation over coffee between someone working on a problem and another can provide insight given by that colleague that leads to a solution of a nasty problem. That alone, in math, can be grounds for authorship, even if the first person does essentially everything else. That would probably be unusual in other fields. But progress in pure math, especially, is driven by "insight", not by following some process, though that process is necessary.
So, in my view and experience, though it is dated, the assumption by working mathematicians is that each of the authors contributed some essential insight to the problem and its solution. It would have nothing to do with hierarchical positioning of the authors.
I hope that is still true, and that most mathematicians find gift authorship abhorrent. There will be exceptions, of course, as there are to most things.

Note that the above might not apply to undergraduate research, which is of a different kind, also with a few exceptions. This is mostly due to time constraints on such things.

yeah, that is the view I'd have assumed myself. (Apparetly, that's not shared by many among the people I talk to). Since I see around two conflicting positions, I was wondering which one is more popular.

I'd remark via some anecdata that the trend of leaving advisers off of thesis work papers is declining at least somewhat in math and CS. It's now mixed enough that I personally can't make heads nor tails of any inclusion/exclusion of an adviser without further information.

As a pure mathematician very much still in the game (I'm taking a pause from reading job applications at this very moment), I agree that everything Buffy says is still up to date.  But I would add what @user1149748 says in another answer as a caveat.

I don't think people jump to conclusions about this, when it comes to a single paper. It is understood that sometimes the situation will be closer to one of your extremes, and sometimes closer to the other.
Where it matters more is when looking at someone's body of work, for example when the PhD student applies for postdoctoral positions. People definitely notice if all or most of someone's work is co-authored with a senior mentor, and the assumption will be that the student is not yet able to work independently.
This is also partly what recommendation letters are for. The advisor can give more detail in the letter about the student's contribution toward joint projects.

I agree with this answer. You simply can't tell from just looking at the paper, and everyone will know that. Wo it's pointless to try to decipher who may have done what and how much: You'd have to talk to the authors about it, or at least know their style of work.

So you think there's no particular assumption that the typical mathematician would have about individual contributions?
